# Roller coaster down a Bezier Curve

Tags: calculus, graphing-functions, parametric

Say we have the following Bezier curve:

$$x(t)=110t^3-120t^2+60t$$
$$y(t)=100t^3-150t^2+50$$
$$Where \quad 0\leq t  \leq 1$$

[image: Bezier curve parametric equations mapping the track of the roller coaster]

This curve maps out the shape of the roller coaster track. Now assuming there are no frictional forces acting on the rollercoaster, only gravity, how could one find an equation which models the motion of the roller coaster down said function with respect to time?

Here is my method (which didn't work):

So I begin with the equation for acceleration down a slope. Then differentiate the bezier curve to find the slope at any point along the function.

$$a=g\sin{\theta}$$

$$\theta = \tan^{-1}{\left |\frac{dy}{dx}\right |} = \tan^{-1}{\left |\frac{\frac{dy}{dt}}{\frac{dx}{dt}}\right |}$$

$$=\tan^{-1}{\left |\frac{300t^2-300t}{330t^2-240t+60}\right |}$$

$$\therefore \theta = \tan^{-1}{\left | \frac{10t^2-10t}{11t^2-8t+2} \right |}$$

So this expression for $\theta$ should give the instantaneous angle of the slope at any point along the curve. Now substituting this expression for theta within $a=g\sin{\theta}$.

$$a(t)=g\sin{\left | \frac{10t^2-10t}{11t^2-8t+2} \right |}$$

Here is where I am stuck. I understand that the above equation is not with respect to *"real"* time. The bezier curve simply maps out the general shape of the track and is not a displacement function with respect to time.

So how could one generate a function which modelled the acceleration, and therefore the velocity and displacement, with respect to time? I swear there should be a simplistic way to do this.

Thank you!

Comment: if you want v(t) and s(t) then why don't you integrate a w.r.t. to t

Comment: If you assume no friction, then use conservation of energy. You have the potential energy $mgy$ and kinetic energy $\frac12 mv^2$, and they must be equal.

Comment: I have thought about using Energy equations. However wouldn't you then need an h(t) function? The change in height over time? Then I run into the same problem as the bezier curve only maps the shape of the track, and not the movement of the cart with respect to time.

Comment: You could also use a new time variable $\tau$ and calculate $dt/d\tau$

Comment: Sorry about that, the original equation was typed incorrectly. It is changed now. The subsequent calculations were using the correct equation though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since our curve $\gamma$ is given in terms of some arbitrary parameter $t$ we shall express "everything" in terms of this $t$, in particular the "real time" $\tau=\tau(t)$. Let $v$ be the "physical speed", i.e., the speed with respect to $\tau$, of the roller coaster. Then
$$v(t)={ds\over d\tau}={s'(t)\over \tau'(t)}\ ,\tag{1}$$
whereby 
$$s'(t)=\sqrt{x'^2(t)+y'^2(t)}$$
is the derivative of the arc length function $t\mapsto s(t)$ along $\gamma$. On the other hand  conservation of energy implies 
$${m\over2} v^2(t)=mg\bigl(50-y(t)\bigr)\ ,$$
so that we have
$$v(t)=\sqrt{2g\bigl(50-y(t)\bigr)}\ .\tag{2}$$
Introducing this into $(1)$ we obtain the following explicit formula for the unknown function $t\mapsto\tau(t)$:
$$\tau'(t)=\sqrt{\strut x'^2(t)+y'^2(t)\over2g\bigl(50-y(t)\bigr)}\qquad(0\leq t\leq 1)\ .$$
I don't think that you can express $\tau(t)$ in elementary terms. If you are just interested in the "physical speed" of the car at various points of the track you can use $(2)$ directly.